# pg_dump a custom data type

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

I'm transferring select tables from my server to my laptop to work on locally. Dumping the entire db is infeasible due to space constraints on my laptop. One of the columns of one table is a custom data type, and when restoring I get the following error:

`pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  type "custom_data_type" does not exist`

There are two ways I could solve this problem, but I'm having trouble finding instructions online to:

1. Ensure that the datatypes on which a table depends are included in `pg_dump
2. Find the create script for the custom data type

Comment: You did a pg_dump on the entire database, and the type creation wasn't included?

Comment: No, I'm just dumping a few tables so I can work on them locally.

Comment: @raphael Did `--schema-only` work for you? I have a similar problem and I can't find a way to include user-defined types in a dump.

Comment: @michal.dul, yes it did work for me. I did have to sort through a lot of SQL to find it. Could've probably just dumped the `public` schema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pg_dump` has the option:

> -s
>   --schema-only
>
> Dump only the object definitions (schema), not data.
>
> This option is the inverse of --data-only. It is similar to, but for historical reasons not identical to, specifying --section=pre-data --section=post-data.
>
> (Do not confuse this with the --schema option, which uses the word "schema" in a different meaning.)

Which, unless your source database has a ton of DDL, should be OK for you. If your source does have a ton of DDL, you can manually extract the type creation script from the `pg_dump` output with your text editor of choice.

Comment: It's a research database, so used by many people... rather messy, the dump was a lot of sql. But this did work for me.